# In OpenCV, after zooming on image, how to get back to standard mouse cursor?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an application where I crop parts of an image and save them in OpenCv 4 using Python, first drawing rectangles before saving (SSCCE below). Some of the images are *very* large, so it is helpful to zoom in on them before selecting regions to crop.

The problem is once you've zoomed on an image, the mouse cursor permanently toggles to the interactive hand. Then clicking/dragging only serves to translate the position of the image in the window (unless I go back out to full size, but then I can't draw rectangles on the zoomed-in image).

So my question is once I've zoomed in, how can I get from this:

[image: hand]

back to this:

[image: pointer]

So I can get back to drawing rectangles on the zoomed in image?  I'd love to be able to right click to get back to the pointer (some magic with `cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN`), but maybe there is some built-in way to do it I'm just ignorant of?

One thing that sort of works is when I changed my program so that it is *right* button presses/releases that draws the rectangles, so then there is no longer any interference with the native left-click navigation. The problem is I can draw more precise rectangles when I have an arrow than when I have a hand. So while this is a hack I can use as a workaround, it would be really nice if I could toggle back to the arrow for drawing rectangles while zoomed in.

**SSCE**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Insert your path to file here:
input_path = r'C:/image0000.bmp'
image = cv2.imread(input_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  
(im_h, im_w) = image.shape
max_d = np.max([im_h, im_w])
line_width = int(np.ceil(max_d/1000))
image_to_show = image.copy() # np.copy(image)
mouse_pressed = False
s_x = s_y = e_x = e_y = -1

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global image_to_show, s_x, s_y, e_x, e_y, mouse_pressed

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_pressed = True
        s_x, s_y = x, y
        image_to_show = np.copy(image)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if mouse_pressed:
            image_to_show = np.copy(image)
            cv2.rectangle(image_to_show, (s_x, s_y),
                          (x, y), (255, 255, 255), line_width)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        mouse_pressed = False
        e_x, e_y = x, y
        print(s_x, s_y, e_x, e_y)

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', mouse_callback)
while True:
    cv2.imshow('image', image_to_show)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)           
    if k == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

In MFC framework, I use GetWindowHandle and SetClassLong (), then use SendMessage to this window and force it to refresh

```
HWND hWnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle ("SrcView");
if (event == CV_EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN || flag == CV_EVENT_FLAG_RBUTTON)
    SetClassLongPtr (hWnd, GCLP_HCURSOR,  (LONG_PTR)pDlgMain->m_cursorDrag);
else
    SetClassLongPtr (hWnd, GCLP_HCURSOR,  (LONG_PTR)LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));

SendMessage (hWnd, WM_SETCURSOR, NULL, NULL);
```

Maybe find the corresponded ones of these three functions in python may be helpful.